# readfile() or file_get_contents() for image output/processing

Tags: php, image, file, file-get-contents, readfile

Which one is more optimised for lowest CPU usage ? If i understand correctly, i should use readfile() when outputting the image without altering it, and file_get_contents() when i need to process it as a string.

Is this code correct ?

```
if(file_exists($CACHE_FILE_PATH) && empty($customcolor)) {
    $path = $CACHE_FILE_PATH;
    $image = readfile($CACHE_FILE_PATH); 

} else {

    $image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($remote_image)); // Load the requested image

    // ********************** CROP PIXELS
    $imagesource = $image;
    $removeLeft = 0.075 * $size;
    $removeRight = 0.075 * $size;
    $removeTop = 0.0375 * $size;
    $removeBottom = 0.1125 * $size;

    $image = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($imagesource) - ($removeLeft + $removeRight), imagesy($imagesource) - ($removeTop + $removeBottom));
    imagecopy($image, $imagesource, 0, 0, $removeLeft, $removeTop, imagesx($image), imagesy($image));
    imagedestroy($imagesource);
    // ***************************


    // Output the image
    if (empty($customcolor))    { 
        imagejpeg($image, $CACHE_FILE_PATH, 93); 
    } else {
        imagejpeg($image, NULL, 93); 
    }
}
imagedestroy($image);
exit();
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Just because the code works doesn't mean that it's automatically off-topic here.